# Non Solved Android Studios issue, Unfortunately

Tags: java, android

I found out, that when I create a layout, and Java file, I'm making a codes, so when I press button, it takes me to the another activity.

I have called already 9 methods to send me to the other activity, 3 or 4 in a MainJava class, and 4 in a layout, and everything works fine.

But now 1 button, in the new layout, doesn't work and says "Unfortunately app has stopped". I can't figure out where is the real problem, but the code is like the other buttons, which work well.

ac_phone

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/phone"
        android:contentDescription="@string/phone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Xiaomi M4 16GB Mobile Phone"
        android:id="@+id/textView48"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#852121" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:id="@+id/textView49"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView48"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:textColor="#852121" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Resolution:1920x1080 "
        android:id="@+id/textView50"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView49"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView49"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView49"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Micro-SIM"
        android:id="@+id/textView51"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView50"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView50"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView50"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Wi-Fi, dual-band, Wi-Fi Direct, DLNA, hotspot"
        android:id="@+id/textView52"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView51"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView51"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView51"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="13MP camera"
        android:id="@+id/textView53"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView52"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView52"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView52"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="3GB Ram"
        android:id="@+id/textView54"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView53"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView53"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView53"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/phoneStart"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I make the onClick button:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Level 3"
        android:id="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:onClick="sendPhone"
        android:background="@drawable/phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView45" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course i make a command in the Java File:

```
 public void sendPhone(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), phoneclass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And i create manifest file:

```
activity android:name=".phoneclass">
```

As i said before, other 9 buttons works well, but one button is getting: "Unfortunately, app has stoped working".

```
05-04 19:35:26.800 2437-2437/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: dynamochest.myapplication, PID: 2437
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dynamochest.myapplication/dynamochest.myapplication.phoneclass}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                 at dynamochest.myapplication.phoneclass.onCreate(phoneclass.java:12)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                 at dynamochest.myapplication.phoneclass.onCreate(phoneclass.java:12) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                 at dynamochest.myapplication.phoneclass.onCreate(phoneclass.java:12) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12441612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                                                 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                 at dynamochest.myapplication.phoneclass.onCreate(phoneclass.java:12) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is really strange thing, everything works, but that 1 button.

Any Ideas where the problem hides?

Comment: Now the button  started to work. Who can explain this? It happened like third time.

Comment: I can't post logcat when the program crashed

Comment: Why can't you post the logcat?

Comment: And please copy your code into the question. Do not use images.

Comment: Because i'm not sure how to import the code without posting the image.

Comment: Select it using your mouse. Right click copy. Come here. [Edit] your question. Paste it in the box.

Comment: Oh, thanks cricket, you just showed to me how to to that! :D

Comment: Can you also post your logcat output?

Comment: Is there any large size image you're loading in your xml file?

Comment: Yes there is, like 250 width, and 220 height

Comment: This big image is on the phoneclass

Comment: I suspect that image might be causing some issue, try to replace any small image and see if it works.

Comment: This didn't helped

Comment: Please post your entire XML code, the ac_code layout.

Comment: What is the size of this image "@drawable/phone" ?

Comment: 120 dp on width and height

Comment: or you mean full image size?

Comment: Size: 31,8 KB (32.601 bytes)

Comment: And it works again. I have no idea whats happening, but now im thinking that when the emulator stays alive for a longer time, it starts to work...

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32245016/3701433

Comment: Note the line in logcat: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Comment: @prudhvi this doesnt even allows me to import in the same type like showed.

Comment: @Dale Wilson, how to fix this error? any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your layouts are nested too deeply or possibly even recursive.  Alternatively as some have suggested, maybe your images are so big that they don't all  fit in the phone's memory at the same time.

Comment: But all image's are like 20-30 KB. I can't make any smaller, and the suggested page, with android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest, it doesnt loads to me in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have traced your logcat, it's telling that the error seems to be caused by out of memory, which would usually occur when you have large sized images. Try to look at this link also, if this might help you. [App crashes on change of ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013468/app-crashes-on-change-of-imageview).

Also, are you using an actual device or just an emulator? If you are using an emulator, try to increase size allocations. If you have a device that you can test, try it as well and check if you'll experience the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it's an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have large size images in your layout file which is causing the `OutOfMemoryError`. As the Android training guide states

> If you're not careful, bitmaps can quickly consume your available
>   memory budget leading to an application crash due to the dreaded
>   exception: java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

You can try loading your images efficiently by following the lessons below

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

There are some good solutions to smiliar questions in SO

[Out of memory error when inflating simple xml layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767636/out-of-memory-error-when-inflating-simple-xml-layout-in-android)

Answer (score -2):

Try using "ActivityName.this" instead of just "this" in `Intent intent = new Intent(this, phoneclass.class);`

Comment: There is no difference between `this` and `ActivityName.this` for the scope that is shown in the image.